# Did the actor for Gideon have an accident that caused him to be less prominent than usual?

Tags: character, criminal-minds

In *Criminal Minds* season 1 episode 11 "Blood Hungry", the episode starts and Gideon is in crutches and has a cast on his foot. He is barely in the episode and is removed from all the action, *which is very unusual.*

It almost seemed like maybe the actor had a real life injury and had to be partially written out of the episode. Did the actor for Gideon have any kind of accident that caused him to be less prominent than usual in this episode?

Comment: Can't find any indication it was a real injury so it's possible it was just a scheduling thing. Perhaps they needed him off-screen filming scenes from another episode,

Comment: Of course, given Patinkin's feelings about the show...perhaps he was just feeling *huffy* that week! :)